# Looking for a related post plugin which slides-in like the one at inc.com does

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, post-thumbnails

Does anybody know a Wordpress "related post" plugin with behavior like the one at inc.com. For a demo, visit any article at inc.com (ex: http://www.inc.com/guides/2010/10/how-to-design-a-great-about-us-page.html) scroll down to the end of the article and you will notice a box sliding in from the bottom right corner of the page.

Although this is just like any other related post plugin, I feel its behavior increases site retention.

Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin I think you're looking for is http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/upprev-nytimes-style-next-post-jquery-animated-fly-in-button/

> "Just like the NYTimes button, upPrev
>   allows WordPress site admins to
>   provide the same functionality for
>   their readers. When a reader scrolls
>   to the bottom of a single post, a
>   button animates in the page’s bottom
>   right corner, allowing the reader to
>   select the next available post in the
>   single post’s category (the category
>   is also clickable to access an archive
>   page). If no next post exists, no
>   button is displayed."

Comment: Bingo! that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you Christopher, for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

You can do that without the plugin via the same type of jQuery function the plugin uses:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772434/looking-for-alternative-to-this-fly-by-in-wordpress-plugin

Comment: Christopher's suggestion works out of the box, no custom coding required.

Comment: Of course it works without any extra work, but the point of WordPress Answers is to be a collaborative Q&A site, where other people down the line will look for your same question and will be interested in different answers.

Answer (score 0):

i use http://mitcho.com/code/yarpp/
very good , customizable and with many settings

Comment: While plugin is indeed good, I don't remember it having such scroll-triggered option natively?..

Comment: oh you're right. i clicked the link, scrolled down and saw the "related posts" underneath the post itself. my fault.

Comment: but i think its really easy to do it by your own. use this plugin, style it, add a few lines of javascript. done

Comment: Christopher's suggestion works out of the box, no custom coding required.